# SQL Loader - strip LF when loading

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I have a flat file loaded using Sql Loader.
I need to add a control when loading to strip all LF inside the values of the column MYFIELD2 for instance.

The columns are separated using '|' and I have the following control file:

```
    LOAD DATA TRUNCATE into table MYTABLE fields terminated by '|' 
    trailing nullcols
    (COD,DAT DATE "YYYYMMDDHH24MISS",
     DATMOD DATE "YYYYMMDDHH24MISS",MYFIELD1, MYFIELD2)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2612348048

Comment: Actually I've changed the solution, and I will modify the spool from this table because it is filled in by replication. So the solution was to use REGEXP_REPLACE(NOMVAL, '[[:space:]]', ' '). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(MyColumn, CHAR(10), ' ') FROM MyTable
```

You may also want to replace CHAR(13).